# Security concerns regarding username / password vs secret URL

Tags: security, web, password-protection

I have a simple site with a sign-up form. Currently the user can complement their registration with (non-critical, "low security") information not available at the time of the sign-up, through a personal (secret) URL.

I.e., once they click submit, they get a message like:

> *Thanks for signing up. You can **complement** your registration by adding information through this personal URL:*
>         http://www.example.com/extra_info/cwm8iue2gi

Now, my client asks me to extend the application to allow users to **change their registration completely**, including more sensitive information such as billing address etc.

My question: **Are there any security issues with having a secret URL instead of a full username / password system?**

The only concern I can come up with is that URLs are stored in the browser history. This doesn't worry me much though. Am I missing something?

It's not the end of the world if someone changes some other users registration info. (It would just involve some extra manual labor.) I will not go through the extent of setting up https for this application.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is not appropriate for sensitive information because it's part of the HTTP request URL, which is not encrypted and shows up in many places such as proxy and other server logs. <strike>Even using HTTPS, you can't encrypt this part of the payload, so it's not an appropriate way to pass the token.</strike>

BTW, another problem with this scheme is if you send the URL to the user via email. That opens up several more avenues for attack.

A better scheme would require some small secret that is not in the email. But it can be challenging to decide what that secret should be. Usually the answer is: password.

Comment: 1) Usernames / passwords are sent in clear text as well when using HTTP, so I bet it shows up in most places where the url shows up. 2) *IF* I indeed used HTTPS, the URL would also be encrypted I believe.

Comment: 1) Not true. URLs are in access logs, including proxy access logs. HTTP packets are transient. 2) You are correct; fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Another potential problem lies with the users themselves.  Most folks realize that a password is something they should try to protect.  However, how many users are likely to recognize that they ought to be making some sort of effort to protect your secret URL?

Comment: Yes. I've recognized this concern and taken special care telling the users this when dealing out their personal addresses... Good point though. +1

Comment: Unfortunately, they're very unlikely to read and/or understand that message.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's probably not the case. Users routinely ignore and/or barely skim messages presented to them in UIs.  You can smack up a big, flashing, red "IMPORTANT", and they'll still ignore it, particularly if it's long-ish.  You're best off sticking with a protection paradigm that most users already understand.  If they want to add the extra information, give them a way to authenticate to protect that information.

Comment: Ok. I was more interested in the technical aspects though... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that although it is hard to guess the URL for any specific user, given enough users it becomes relatively easy to guess a correct url for SOME user.

This would be a classic example of a [birthday attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack).

ETA: Missed the part about the size of the secret, so this doesn't really apply in your case, but will leave the answer here since it might apply in the more general case.

Comment: I can easily make sure that the URL have the same "entropy" as any combination of username / passwords. I.e., the "birthday attack" would be just as applicable to a username password, no?

Comment: This is only true if the space is not sparse. He has a 51-bit space (about 3 quadrillion possibilities). If everyone on the planet has an URL, he's using about 0.00016% of his space. That's pretty sparse. The question then is how fast you can brute force, but that part of the problem is trivially fixed by adding a few more bits. This is still a bad solution, but not because of brute-force attacks. It's bad because of HTTP.

Comment: @aioobe: correct. username+password is just a longer token with less entropy per bit. Your token has more entropy than username+password if usernames are known, and nearly as much if usernames are non-random.

Comment: @RobNapier, the example url is just... an example. I have even more "secret" characters in my application.

Answer (score 0):

The "secret URL" is often referred to as security by obscurity.  The issue is that it is super simple to write a script that will attempt various combinations of letters, symbols, and numbers to brute force hack this scheme.

So if any sensitive information is stored you should definitely use at least a username and password to secure it.

Comment: While I agree that this particular scheme is not good, it's not because it's obscurity. The page is protected by an approximately 51-bit secret (assuming it's 10 lowercase letters plus numbers). This is not fundamentally different than a username and password, particularly if the username is well known. This still isn't a good approach because of how HTTP works, but the problem isn't the "secret URL." Replace the words "secret URL" with "token" or "automatically-generated password" which is what this really is. Your brute-force approach is equally applicable to a password.

Comment: Agreed Rob. I hadn't considered it in that light.

Answer (score 0):

> can complement their registration with (non-critical, "low security") information

It's hard to imagine what user-supplied information really is "low-security"; even if you are asking for a password and a username from your customers you are potenitally violating a duty of care to your customers; a large propertion of users will use the same username/password on multiple sites. Any information about your users and potentially a lot of information about transactions can be used by a third party to compromise the identity of that user.

Any information about the user should be supplied in an enctypted format (e.g. via https). And you should take appropriate measures to protect the data you store (e.g. hashing passwords).

Your idea of using a secret URL, means that only you, the user, anyone on the same network as the user, in the vicinity of a user on wifi, connected to any network between you and the user, or whom has access to the users hardware will know the URL. Of course that's not considering the possibility of someone trying a brute force attack against the URLs.

C.

Comment: Assuming I go with http regardless, how is this different from a username / password form submission?

Comment: It's easier to brute-force. And you don't have to use https to encrypt a password.

Comment: why is it easier to brute force? and if I don't use https, the password is sent in clear text... (I can't encrypt a password either)

Answer (score 0):

The secret URL means nothing if you're not using SSL.  If you're still having the end-user transmit their identifying information across the Internet in the clear, then it doesn't matter how you're letting them in: They are still exposed.

Comment: So you're saying that secret url and login-forms are just as (in)secure if used over HTTP?

Comment: Yep. They stop the casual "hacker", but that's not normally who we're worried about. Internet security hinges on encryption. Obscurity will only take you so far. SSL certs are cheap and easy to install and there's really no good reason NOT to use SSL for authentication and protection of personal information.