# How secure is it to call "secret" URLs in an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, security, networking

We want to use a web service in our app which obviously requires to call a URL. It's not HTTPS, just plain old HTTP, using NSURLConnection.

The problem is: This web service is VERY expensive and every thousand calls costs us real money. The fear is that someone could figure out which URL we call and then misuse that, letting the costs explode. There is no way for us to track if a call to that web service was legitimate.

We're calculating based on how many apps we sell, multiplied by an assumption of how often that app will be used per user in average. We have some good statistics on which we base our assumptions.

Are there known ways of figuring out which URL an app is calling on the Internet to retrieve information?

Comment: What you are doing is fundamentally insecure. You will not be able to hide this information form an attacker.  This is just "(in)security through obscurity".

Answer (score 12):

You could easily use a network sniffer while the phone is on WiFi to figure out this information. It sounds like it is actually critical that you use SSL with some sort of secure token in the URL.

If this is not an option perhaps you can provide your own proxy service that would use SSL and security tokens? Proxy also grants the ability to throttle requests and block users known to be malicious. Throttling puts an upper bound on the expense each user can incur within a given time interval. Another benefit of a proxy is that it allows one to gather statistics and measure the costs incurred by different users facilitating malicious user detection and business planning. Proxy could also save you some money if the service behind it is stateless by adding a cache that would remove a lot of expensive calls.

Comment: +1 Do note that SSL can still be sniffed with a proxy like Charles if your program blindly trusts the certificate. It needs to check that the certificate is signed by *you*, not just "some trusted signer." Also, it is still always possible to reverse engineer your program to determine the payload, but a verified SSL proxy will significantly raise the bar on iOS, leaving mostly highly motivated attackers rather than casual attackers.

Comment: You're right about these points. One way to further increase the security of the system is to use both SSL and a security token and make the token derived from a factor outside the application, like a password only known to the authorized user (appropriate security to usability balance should be considered). Note that the function used to derive tokens must be one-way. Proxy grants extra security by allowing you to throttle or block the requests thus putting an upper bound on the expense a malicious user can incur on the system owner within a given time interval.

Comment: Took me a few moments to get your point here, but agreed. If you can tie the "please let me talk to you" token to a user-specific piece of information (like an account), then you can strongly limit abuse. If you can't, then you can weakly limit abuse by throttling based on IP.

Comment: -1 ssl cannot be used to hide urls.  An attacker can still obtain this information by decompiling the binary or using a debugger.

Comment: @Rook, SSL does hide the GET portion of the URL. I've made the same mistake: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584162/security-concerns-regarding-username-password-vs-secret-url/7584387#7584387. As I've noted in my previous comment, forcing the attacker to reverse engineer an iOS binary does provide a significant barrier that URL sniffing does not.

Comment: @Rook Good point, one should actually use SSL **together with** secure tokens derived from some external factor.

Comment: User-based token throttling is a much stronger protection, and obscurity alone is not sufficient against dedicated attackers. But that does not mean that all approaches are equally attackable. Getting this traffic onto an SSL proxy provides significant benefits to the OP and to the user (in protecting their traffic), and sets the stage for future improvements. It shouldn't be discounted because it does not stop all attacks.

Comment: @RobNapier I agree. Dedicated attacker may even be able to generate correct secure token after obtaining the external factor (e.g. password) via some other means. Ability to block and throttle users allows to contain the loses incurred by such attackers.

Answer (score 4):

If the Web service is not encrypted, it would be trivial to use a proxy to intercept the Web requests made by the phone. If the expensive Web service does not offer at least some form of basic authentication, I would seriously reconsider including its URL in a public app.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "trivial" and "proxy"? Is that a WiFi router giving a protocol of what happens? The web service is "protected" by a user id in the URL request. That way they determine their "client". Of course anyone could copy that url and just call it exactly like that on our behalf.

Comment: Sure. There's no need to go mucking around with a router at all. Whenever I'm debugging a network app I'm working on, I fire up my trusted [http://charlesproxy.com] Charles software proxy, and set my iphone's WiFi   settings to use my desktop's address as a proxy. With this, I can monitor all the http requests being sent and received by my phone. I would highly suggest using such software to test it yourself -- you'll be able to see what anyone else can also glean from your network requests.

Answer (score 3):

Using plain URLs is a sure way of letting script kiddies run you out of business. If there is no way for you to track if a call to the expensive web service was legitimate, set up your own web service that fronts the real web service to make sure that your own web service can verify the legitimacy of the call before forwarding the request to the real web service.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's plenty of ways to do this.  For one example, hook up the iPhone to a wifi network, in which the router has a transparent proxy.  Examine the proxy's logs.  You'll see all URLs.  Depends how determined your users are, but this is rather easy.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that people who jailbreak their devices could possibly look at your application, I believe it is possible to examine traffic like any other device (laptop, tablet, etc.) if someone was sniffing traffic over a WiFi hotspot using applications such as [WireShark](http://wireshark.org). However, I doubt there would be much risk of this over a cellular 3G network.

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

As many have said, yes, **it's easy to figure out the urls your app requests**.

**Note about HTTPS:**
But since you are using HTTPS you are okay because over HTTPs the domain will be obscured to the IP address, and **people cannot see the URL query string parameters**. For example, if your URL was https://somewebsite.com?uid=mylogin&pass=mypass, they definitely won't be able to see "uid=mylogin&pass=mypass", and they probably can only see the IP address, not the domain name itself. (see https://serverfault.com/questions/186445/can-an-attacker-sniff-data-in-a-url-over-https)

**Sidenote:**
Might be safe to assume that Apple performs some sort of HTTP request diagnostics when they review your app -- which would make sense because it's in their best interest to try and figure out what your app does from many angles.